# undefined reference to `GdiplusStartup@12'

Tags: c++, linker, g++, gdi+

I'm finding a way to use GDI+ library with g++ compiler, I have read some guildlines on the web and still meet with problem...
Here is my code:

```
#include "gdiplus.h"  
using namespace Gdiplus;

// Skip Lines

GdiplusStartup(&lpGdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, &gdiplusStartupOutput);
// Skip Lines
```

And I have already used the compiler switch as below:

> ```
> g++ -Wall -mwindows -lgdiplus -I"C:\MinGW\include" -I"C:\MinGW\include\gdiplus" -L"C:\MinGW\lib" -g3 -finput-charset=GBK "$(FilePath)" -o "$(FileDir)\$(FileNameNoExt).exe"
> ```

Still I got such errors:

> ```
> C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccjX3mCb.o: In function `WinMain@16':
> D:/Projects/cyau/cyau_pre4_20120226/cyau_main.cpp:65: undefined reference to `GdiplusStartup@12'
> C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccjX3mCb.o: In function `Z15ExitApplicationP6HWND__jjl':
> D:/Projects/cyau/cyau_pre4_20120226/cyau_main.cpp:128: undefined reference to `GdiplusShutdown@4'
> ```

So what's wrong with it? Is there anything more I need?
Thanks for help...

Comment: Type "mingw gdiplus" in a google query and take the first hit.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Not that thing, friend. I have read through the article. And even download the library to replace the original one, but errors above remained... Do the compiler setting relates with that?

Comment: I've got the same problem with cygwin's g++.  It is rather frustrating.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar messages as you and after some research I've come to the following: place `-lgdiplus` after `*.cpp` files on the command line. Example:

```
g++ -mwindows program.cpp -lgdiplus
```

That command compiled my GDI+ program.

Comment: The -l option tells linker to link the file named `libgdiplus.o`, it works because you HAVE this library file in your physical file system.  
Maybe you're right but this question leads to a common question which is "How can I use .lib(MSVC static library) while compiling with g++ or gcc"  
Achieving this goal can be troublesome, due to many requirements must be satisfied...  
Anyway, thank you for the suggestion.^ω^

Comment: @cuter44: Little correction: the -l option tells the linker to link file named `libgdiplus.a`. It is in `lib` subdirectory of MinGW directory. So why is the *.lib file needed?

Comment: `the -l option tells the linker to link file named libgdiplus.a` Sorry my mistake m(_ _)m. Because I con only find the .lib on the Web at that moment ^ω^b

Comment: The order of the -lgdiplus flag relative to the source file is important. If -lgdiplus is given first, it doesn't work. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. If you are using CodeBlocks
add

-mwindows -lgdiplus

on the other linker options

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPS0j.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twzus.png)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using DevCPP, and had the same issue.

Creating a **`libgdiplus.a`** from a **`gdiplus.def`**
using this command solved my problem:

```
dlltool -k -d gdiplus.def -l libgdiplus.a
```

Initially i was using the command above without the **`-k`** params.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with g++, but I believe the problem is with linking.

Either the gdiplus library isn't getting linked, or it isn't compatabile with g++.
Hopefully that will help you continue tracking down the problem.

Comment: Emmm... Yes, I noticed that it's due to the linker. But all dependent files mentioned are there except the GdiPlus.lib. But they said g++ does not recongize .lib file. Mess...

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS 2015. One program compiles OK.  Another program using the same code gave me the `GdiplusStartup@12'error (and many others).  Fixed the problem by adding GdiPlus.lib to the linker input.  Do not understand why the two programs behave differently, but it works.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30433503)